# Do I need to re-install an unleveled window or just leave it?

Tags: windows

This window was not installed leveled. As you can see from the seam at the bottom, it's slightly slanted.

Will it result in problems later such as water drainage, draft, seal, structural, etc. or is it just an aesthetic issue? What is the proper way to seal this window?

- It's a 5'x5' window.
- It's not operable.
- It's sealed around the flange
  but not stucco'ed or fully nailed down yet.

[image: Interior][image]

Comment: Could leave it as is and finish it, but in a few months/years you keep looking at it and it keeps bugging you that it is not perfect.  That is the time when a hammer goes though it.

Comment: and further to the above comment by @isherwood, sometimes making it level is not noticeably better. Of course, work to level, but if it's off it does not have to be an optic problem, as it depends on what's around it.

Comment: @isherwood Yes I used a level and it shows it's not level. The sides and top seams also show the same slanted gaps so it's definitely not leveled.

Comment: I edited it to better clarify the question, based on OP's statements in the comments above

Answer (score 3):

> As you can see from the seam at the bottom, it's slightly slanted.

How do I know you're house or backyard isn't slanted? Did you actually use a level?

> Is it worth it to take it off and re-install?

If it bugs you today then it will bug you after everything get's finished. Odds are that you'll have curtains/drapes covering this window most of the time so you might not even notice.

Comment: Yes I used a level and it shows it's not level. The sides and top seams also show the same slanted gaps so it's definitely not leveled.

Comment: @manni Nice, so have you decided whether it's worth it to take it off and re-install?

Comment: @MonkeyZeuys do you know if it would result in problems later such as water drainage, draft, seal, structural, etc.? If not I might just leave it but I'm still leaning toward redoing it since the contractor did a bad job on the vapor barrier too. :(

Comment: @manni As long as the window is properly sealed then none of those issues should occur. However, would you personally buy your next house with unlevel windows? Once trim is added around the windows then will the trim be unlevel as well or will the trim be level and further highlight that the window is not level. Overall, yes they should redo it because that is poor workmanship.

Comment: The rough opening seems too narrow to allow proper square and level installation

Comment: @Kris Maybe the window is too large.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yes.   I meant to post this comment on the question.   Sorry

Answer (score 2):

I would take the time and fit it straight.

Once all the finishing goes in you will have a harder job.

Comment: Agree with Solar Mike.  Correct it now while it is easier to remove & put back in.

Comment: Yes, you should fix it right. It will bug you forever if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

Whether this window should be level or can be left off-kilter by a minor amount is a matter of aesthetics. You should also optically consider the level of other visual lines around the window: that of the ceiling/roof trims and that of the sliding door beside it. If they all sort of match then the absolute level matters less.

In any case, the small offset plays no structural role. Once sealed off it will properly prevent drafts and provide thermal insulation.

The main concern is water ingress. For this the window's backward tilt matters (if any) and whether the angle of the window is causing water to run down to one corner where high volumes of water cannot be sufficiently drained away through weeping holes (if any).

What I find more concerning is the lack of a drip edge or flashing at the top of the window, regardless of the tilt. It seems there is some sort of stucco ledge but it does not sufficiently shield the top right corner, since it stops short of the window's edge. Depending in your climate it could advisable to add proper flashing at the top and maybe at the bottom as well, and properly lap the house wrap where accessible.

Comment: as you can see, it's all stucco outside. How can I add proper flashing with stucco in the way?

Comment: @manni it won't be easy but now is a good time to do it if your climate warrants it. Have a look here https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/234407/how-do-i-install-flashing-about-an-existing-window